# Moth that resembles a leaf. What species is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

[image]
[image]

Location: Urban area near the Western Ghats, Kerala, South India

Date: Sometime in September, 2016

Climatic Conditions: Humid, frequent rains.

Brief description:

Head isn't prominent from the dorsal view. Wings outstretched even when at rest. Antennae largely concealed under the fore wings. Also it...um...does a pretty good impression of a leaf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It resembles ***[Pelagodes antiquadraria](http://eol.org/pages/32717669/overview)***, which belongs to the moth *genus* **Pelagodes** in the *family* **[Geometridae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometer_moth)**.

[image: Pelagodes antiquadraria]

**Image Source**: **[FlickRiver](http://www.flickriver.com/photos/tags/pelagodes/interesting/)**

Answer (score -5):

Not a Moth, it's a **Geometrid emerald butterfly.**

http://www.fnanaturesearch.org/images/stories/ns/marked/M/7002.jpg

Comment: But that picture looks quite different from the one above, especially the white lines and maybe the "feathery" edges of the wings.

Comment: Although it belongs to the family of Geometrid, its belongs to a moth genus